# Android Custom Activity

Tags: android, button

http://tinypic.com/r/2v85soh/5

Hi!,

Do you see that bottom arrow pointing up? I want to allow users in Android to be able to drag it and use buttons from there!

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Android has a SlidingDrawer UI component that can be used for this sort of thing: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

Answer (score 0):

Android has a [`SlidingDrawer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) widget, but it's deprecated. I would look online for open source libraries/projects that have implemented this kind of functionality. Perhaps something like this: [AndroidSlideUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)